# Finding a Maclaurin Series for arctan(1/x)

Tags: calculus

LEt $f(x) = \arctan (1/x)$. Can we find a Maclaurin series of $f$?

My thought is to differentiate first to obtain

$$ f'(x) = \dfrac{ - 1/x^2 }{1+1/x^2} = \dfrac{-1}{1+x^2} = - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n x^{2n} $$

and thus

$$ f(x) = C - \sum \dfrac{(-1)^n x^{2n+1}}{2n+1} $$

Notice that as $x \to 0^+$, then $1/x \to \infty$ and thus $f(x) \to \pi/2$. Therefore, $C = \pi/2$. We thus have

$$ f(x) = \pi/2 - \sum \dfrac{(-1)^n x^{2n+1}}{2n+1} $$

and $0<x<1$. Is this valid?

Comment: $arctan(\frac{1}{x})$ is the same as $arccot(x)$. Does this help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the real line $\arctan\frac1x=\begin{cases}\operatorname{arccot}x&\text{if }x>0\\ -\pi+\operatorname{arccot}x&\text{if }x<0\end{cases}$, which has a jump discontinuity at $0$. So no power series converges to $\arctan\frac1x$ in a neighbourhood of $0$. The series you have written is the Taylor series at $0$ of $\operatorname{arccot}$, and that series will converge to $\arctan \frac1x$ for $0<x<1$.